# Why does it compile in Android source?

Tags: android, c++, adb

I'm trying to compile adb (core/adb) on windows using VS2008 manually. 
In the function

```
static __inline__  char*  adb_dirstart( const char*  path )
{
    char*  p  = strchr(path, '/');
    ...
```

I get the error:

```
sysdeps.h(247) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot 
    convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'
```

The return type of strchr as displayed by VS2008 and [described here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) is

```
const char * strchr ( const char * str, int character );
      char * strchr (       char * str, int character );
```

As the argument path is const char*, the first variant returning constant should be used.

So why does it compile in Android SDK? Is there any compiler switch used in the build scripts?

Comment: adb source does not follow the C/C++ standard, and is by no means portable. You need to do the job yourself.

Comment: you can see the Android build environment requirements at https://source.android.com/source/building.html Yours is not supported

Comment: @ALL: Interesting. Many thanks! One customer decided to use android tablet for an industrial product with very hard requirements. My research today makes me think, android is still more a toy, than a serious platform.

Comment: If it is gcc, compile option `-Wwrite-string` may be used to emit warning for such code.

Comment: Sorry typo, should be `-Wwrite-strings` .